# ExpressionEngine 3 .gitignore

Tags: .gitignore

How are everyones .gitignore files looking in the latest iteration of EE?

Mine .gitignore is included below.

Is there anymore secret data / files that should not be in the repo?

```
# Capistrano
config
capfile

# Cache
system/user/cache/*

# Settings
system/user/config/*

#Images
images/avatars/*
!images/avatars/index.html
images/captchas/*
!images/captchas/index.html
images/forum_attatchments/*
images/forum_attatchments/index.html
images/member_photos/*
!images/member_photos/index.html
images/signature_attatchments/*
!images/signature_attatchments/index.html
images/smileys/*
!images/smileys/index.html
images/uploads/*
!images/uploads/index.html
```

## Update 09/11/15

Added cache above due to tip from @seavers

Answer (score 3):

Here's the cache directory:

system/user/cache/*